# Performance difference between tf.boolean_mask and tf.gather + tf.where

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow

[`tf.boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) reads much nicer than then combination of `tf.gather` and `tf.where`. However, it seems to be much slower in the 1-D case:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# use this shape
shape = [5000]

# create random mask m and dummy vector v
m = tf.random.uniform(shape) > 0.5
v = tf.ones(shape)

# apply boolean_mask to select elements from v based on boolean mask m:
%timeit tf.boolean_mask(v, m)
# 1.23 ms ± 1.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# do the same with gather and where:
%timeit tf.gather(v, tf.where(m))
# 107 µs ± 349 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Admittedly, the results have slightly different shapes:

```
tf.boolean_mask(v, m).shape
# TensorShape([2578])
tf.gather(v, tf.where(m)).shape
# TensorShape([2578, 1])
```

This can be fixed by squeezing out the additional dimension, which makes it 50% slower:

```
%timeit tf.squeeze(tf.gather(v, tf.where(m)))
# 149 µs ± 343 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Still, this is almost a factor 10 faster than using `boolean_mask`. Is there a subtle difference, or is `tf.boolean_mask` just missing an optimization for the 1-D case?

PS: There seems to be a strong dependence on the size of the tensor, too. For `shape = [5000000]`, the performance is on par.

Answer (score 0):

It seems boolean_mask is wrapper of gather + where：